# Multiple Sender Profiles with Same From Address but different Reply Addresses?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, setup, deliverability

Hey just wondering if anyone has done a similar setup? Using the same From address in multiple sender profiles but different reply redirects.

Info@BestCompany <-From Address - Same from Address for all the sender profiles below

```
Kevin@BestCompany.com <-Reply Address 1. - Sender Profile Kevin
Stacey@BestCompany.com <-Reply Address 2 - Sender Profile Stacey
Ryan@BestCompany.com <-Reply Address 2  - Sender Profile Ryan
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with this, however it might be also worth thinking of ONE sender profile with dynamic from address based on a data extension instead of creating tons of sender profiles that copy information for a large part.

Plus: Your from address is either a bad example, or you need to be careful.
From Address MUST be from your authenticated subdomain, which is unlikely to be Bestcompany.com but rather something like mail.bestcompany.com. Just saying.

About dynamic from address:

All this requires the business rule “Enhanced Sender Profiles" that support can enable, or you'll get: “Format of the E-Mail Address is not valid…”.

This enables the section “Populate Reply-to Address Dynamically” in  “Reply Mail Management” in setup.

You can then build any logic in Code snippets, e.g. one called "Dynamic-SP-Name"", and your logic inside should create a variable containing your from name, e.g. in variable:
@dynamicSenderProfileName

then you can reference this logic in the fields in RMM:

```
%%=ContentBlockByKey("Dynamic-SP-Name")=%%%%=v(@dynamicSenderProfileName)=%%
```

[image]

Comment: Yes I used a bad example, it is a subdomain like you stated. I'm confused on setting up the RMM though, do I need one email address as an overall "capture" for all replies to any email sent from marketing cloud to use for the Reply address definition? If so is this a new email built on the subdomain for MC that I need to provision with IT?

Also, is the enhanced sender profile the ideal route to go? Creating one sender profile with the dynamic SP for the different from addresses and then using the RMM logic to dynamically populate the reply to address in Marketing Cloud?

Comment: Should add a follow up as well, the SAP was setup when I was not present and it looks like Salesforce didn't setup RMM on the account since it should be filled by them. What is recommended to get this up, reach out to Salesforce and have them complete RMM? In order for them to do so do I need to setup an email address on my end that they can reference? Also, is there a way to setup reply's to emails without RMM if that is a time road block, where they will work currently without the RMM being configured.